# void function that removes al the non alphabet chars

Tags: c, string

I am trying to write a program that gets several strings until it gets the 'Q' string (this string basically stops the scanf).
Each one of the strings is sent to a function that romoves everything except the letters. For example if I scan 'AJUYFEG78348' the printf should be 'AJUYFEG'.
The problem is that the function has to be void.
I have tried several ways to make the "new array with only letters" printed, but none of them worked.
(Is is not allowed to use strlen function)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void RemoveNonAlphaBetChars(char*);

int main()
{
    int flag=1;
    char array[100]={0};
    while (flag == 1)
    {
        scanf("%s", &array);
        if(array[0] == 'Q' && array[1] =='\0') {
           flag=0;
        }
        while (flag == 1)
        {
           RemoveNonAlphaBetChars(array);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

void RemoveNonAlphaBetChars(char* str)
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    char new_string[100]={0};

    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        if (((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z')) || ((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z')))
        {
            new_string[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }

    }
    printf("%s", new_string);
    return;
}
```

Comment: two approaches: either alocate temp buffer, remove digits, copy back to input, or work inplace, with memory moves. First approach is probably faster.

Comment: There is no reason (that you have given) why "the function has to be void". Just do what's natural to the language.

Comment: The function has to be void because that's what they ask in my course.

Comment: The teacher also said, that we are not allowed to use strlen function.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &array);` => `scanf("%s", array);` BTW.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. Properly implemented, in place approach should be faster. It involves all the same test and move operations, but not the allocation and deallocation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it heavily depends on the data: if there are no chars to remove, it's faster. If there are a lot of chars to remove at the start of the string, and the string is long, and they're not consecutive, it creates a lot of copies. Yes, a very smart implementation would avoid them.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. I've provided an implementation that only makes one move per character, at most.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the function has only one argument, non-const char pointer, hints at the fact that the string is going to be changed in the call (better document it anyway), and it's perfectly all right.

A few fixes to your code can make it right:

First, don't loop to the end of the buffer, just to the end of the string (without `strlen`, it's probably faster too):

```
for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

then don't forget to nul-terminate the new string after your processing:

```
new_string[j] = '\0';
```

Then, in the end (where you're printing the string) copy the new string into the old string. Since it's smaller, there's no risk:

```
strcpy(str,new_string);
```

now `str` contains the new stripped string.

Another approach would be to work in-place (without another buffer): each time you encounter a character to remove, copy the rest of the string at this position, and repeat. It can be inefficient if there are a lot of characters to remove, but uses less memory.

Comment: I've updated my version to address the possibility of there being large runs of characters of both classes. I still think that in-place with care is fundamentally more efficient for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that you are never inserting new characters into the string. That guarantees that the input buffer is large enough to hold the result. It also makes for an easy in-place solution, which is what the `void` return type is implying.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...

void RemoveNonAlphaBetChars(char* str)
{
    char *from, *to;

    for(from = to = str; *from; from++) {
        if(isalpha(*from)) {
            if(from > to) *to = *from;
            to++;
        }
    }
    *to = *from;
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return;
}
```

The pointer `from` steps along the string until it points to a NUL character, hence the simple condition in the loop. `to` only receives the value of `from` if it is a character. The final copy after the loop ensures NUL termination.

**Update**

If you are dealing with 1) particularly large strings, and 2) you have long stretches of letters with *some* numbers in between, and 3) your version of `memmove` is highly optimized compared to copying things manually (e.g. with a special processor instruction), you can  do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
...

void RemoveNonAlphaBetChars(char* str)
{
    char *from, *to, *end;
    size_t len;

    for(from = to = str; *from; from = end) {
        for(; *from && !isalpha(*from); from++) ;
        for(end = from; *end && isalpha(*end); end++) ;
        len = end - from;
        if(from > to) {
            if(len > 1) {
                memmove(to, from, len);
            } else {
                *to = *from;
            }
        }
        to += len;
    }
    *to = *end;
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return;
}
```

The general idea is to find the limits of each range of letters (between `from` and `end`), and copy into `to` block by block. As I stated before though, this version should not be used for the general case. It will only give you a boost when there is a huge amount of data that meets particular conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`void` return type is a common approach to making functions that produce C string results. You have two approaches to designing your API:

- Make a non-destructive API that takes output buffer and its length, or
- Make an API that changes the the string in place.

The first approach would look like this:

```
void RemoveNonAlphaBetChars(const char* str, char *result, size_t resultSize) {
    ...
}
```

Use `result` in place of `new_string`, and make sure you do not go past `resultSize`. The call would look like this:

```
if (flag == 1) { // if (flag == 1), not while (flag == 1)
   char result[100];
   RemoveNonAlphaBetChars(array, result, 100);
   printf("%s\n", result);
}
```

If you decide to use the second approach, move `printf` into `main`, and use `strcpy` to copy the content of `new_string` back into `str`:

```
strcpy(str, new_string);
```

Comment: the function should be like that void RemoveNonAlphaBetChars(char* str) (It is not aloowed to have additional parameters.)

Comment: @Michelle Then use `strcpy` approach (#2).

Comment: @Michelle Do not only add restrictions in a comment under 1 answer.  Better to append to your post such restrictions.  Best to list all restrictions in the initial post.